# python overriding method without re-copying whole code

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

I have a class `Father` whom I call `run` method to do the work. I inherit this class with a `Child` class. This look like this:

```
class Father:
    def __init__(self):
        ...

    def run(self):
        work1()
        work2()
        ....

class Child(Father):
    def run(self):
        pass
```

Usually, I use `pass`, as most of the time, children do same things as father, just being called from distinct contexts. However, sometimes the behavior changes. But when it does, `work1`, `work2`, and so on from `Father` are still being executed. Only a last `workn` should be added.

How is it possible to override `run` method without having to copy the whole code from `Father.run`, and just adding a last `work` instruction? I have tried this, which is working:

```
class Father:
    def run(self):
        work1()
        ...
        run_additionnal_stuf()
    def run_additionnal_stuf(self):
        pass

class Child(Father):
    def run_additionnal_stuf(self):
        work()
```

However, is there any solution more elegant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, if your `Child` class doesn't change a method you don't need to define it with `pass`. Simply do nothing and thanks to [inheritance magic](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance), the child instance will also have that method.

---

As to your actual question, if you only want to **add** functionality to a child instance, you can use [`super`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super). Indeed, from the docs:

> This is useful for accessing inherited methods that have been
>   overridden in a class.

So you could do:

```py
class Child(Father):
    def run(self):
        super().run()
        work_n()
```

---

A simple demonstration:

```py
class Father:
    def run(self):
        print("In Father")

class Child(Father):
    def run(self):
        super().run()
        print("In Child")

f = Father()
c = Child()
f.run()
c.run()
```

And this expectedly prints out:

```
In Father
In Father
In Child
```

Comment: If you use `super()` you have to use it everywhere!  Also in `Father.run()`, otherwise it's possible to build inheritance hierarchies where not all methods are actually called. See: https://fuhm.net/super-harmful/